# Computer freezes when idle

Tags: windows-7, freeze

I have a problem where my computer will randomly freeze. I can not reproduce this by doing anything specific.  It will freeze while idle, or randomly while I use it.

Specs are: http://speccy.piriform.com/results/fi8aBPZrCZuBQiYFcDwlvCo

Attempted solutions:

- running single GPU
- Single RAM, and RAM in different slots
- reinstalling Windows
- replacing SSD/HDD
- replacing PSU
- reinstalling Windows
- checking heat, and making sure it didnt get too high
- checking event logs for criticals or errors

I am running out of solutions, and I've been having this problem for years.

Comment: @fixer1234 Please be a little more thorough with these edits, thanks.

Comment: well if your computer freezes when idle how about you run a program that keeps moving the mouse so it doesn't go idle (I doubt it freezes when idle.. i'm sure it freezes on use as well.. ).  You have to check event viewer.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this error is caused by Windows trying to put your SSD drive to sleep.
Please update your BIOS. That is a must.

Now we can proceed.

1. Update *Intel Rapid Storage Technology* if in use.
2. Set "Put the computer to sleep" to **never** in Power Option settings.
3. [Turn off LPM](http://www.ithacks.com/2012/10/14/fixing-an-ssd-freezing-on-windows-7/)
4. [Change ACHCI to IDE](http://z9.io/2013/11/26/yes-finally-fixed-ssd-freezing-computer/). I don't like this idea but it works for some people.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have bloated capacitors. Look at the capacitors near to the power plugs leading from the power supply to the mother board.

[image: bloated capacitor]

(left is bloated, right is ok)

If this is the case, capacitors can be changed, but it is mostly more expensive than a new mother board.